# Order BY diffrence of two columns using DataMapper

Tags: mysql, ruby-datamapper

I have a mysql table.
It contains 2 Column (startdate,enddate)
Both are of DateTime type
Using sql

```
select * from ABC order by (enddate-startdate) DESC;
```

same thing i want in datamapper...but i m not able to do it
Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, i got one datamapper function to run sql query directly

```
repository(:default).adapter.select('select * from ABC order by (enddate-startdate) DESC')
```